# Can a Blender animation be further edited using Three.js?

Tags: javascript, animation, three.js, blender, .obj

I am trying to simulate a human heart using Three.js and I was just about to start animating a .obj heart model in Blender. But before I do this I'd like to ask if there is any way I can alter the animation once it's loaded into my script.

Basically, I can simulate the heartbeat but I need the option to change its rhythm (intensity, frequency, etc) from the code. If that's not possible however, suggestions are welcome.

I am new to the whole graphics thing (and to javascript to be honest) and I'm just starting to understand how things work so it would be great if I could get a bit of help.

Thanks!

Comment: maybe: what kind of output can you get from Blender that shows up on a webpage?

Comment: apparently I can get an md2 file that can be imported in three.js

Comment: i looked into it, and yes, it's possible. you convert the md2 into json and feed that to three.js. http://oos.moxiecode.com/js_webgl/md2_converter/ now, once you get it into json, you can modify the contents with javascript before feeding it to three.js, or maybe use some commands in three.js to adjust the already-loaded and running animation. that said, the json looked VERY complicated, and i don't think it will be very easy to adjust. possible, but hard, so if you're just starting out, it would be easier to pre-render a few adjustments and toggle between them on the web.

Comment: I was thinking that too, I'll just create a few different animations in the first place and deal with the rest of the functionality. I'll eventually switch to adjusting it from javascript but at a later stage I suppose. Thanks a lot!

Comment: you will be able to change the rythm by changing the animation speed, but changing the intensity of the movement won't be easily feasible. It involves that you compute the position for each vertices. If changing the intensity of the movement is important for your project, the easier would definitely be to use a vertex shader.